# Drawing google charts in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, charts, google-visualization

I want to draw a line graph in google charts with data fetched in Java EE and sent as json. 
Google expects this kind of data.

```html
[
          ['Date', 'total'],
          ['2018-01-01',11],
          ['2018-01-02',2],
          ['2018-01-03',2],
          ['2018-01-04',2],
          ['2018-01-05',7]
        ]
```

But with this code which i have really tried to play around with, the best i have come up with is this.

```js
{"data":[{"2018-01-28":0},{"2018-01-29":0},{"2018-01-30":0},{"2018-01-31":0},{"2018-02-01":0},{"2018-02-02":0},{"2018-02-03":0}]}

This data received from the sql query cannot be used to print the charts. Below is the code
```

```html
package Graphs;

import database.DatabaseUtilities;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import time.GetTime;
import time.ThisWeek;

/**
 *
 * @author phanue
 */
public class Events {
    private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    private static ResultSet resultSet;
    private static String sql;
    private static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    
    public static JsonObject weeksEventsGraph(){
        ThisWeek week = GetTime.weekDates();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        JsonObject data = null;
        
        sql ="SELECT DATE(`eventApprovedOn`) AS eventDate, sum(`eventId`) as total FROM " +
            "events WHERE DATE(eventApprovedOn) >= ? AND DATE(eventApprovedOn) <= ? " +
            "AND `eventStatus` = 1 GROUP BY `eventApprovedOn`";
        
        try {
            preparedStatement = DatabaseUtilities.createConnection(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,week.getStart());
            preparedStatement.setString(2,week.getEnd());
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            for(int i = Calendar.SUNDAY; i <= Calendar.SATURDAY; i++) {
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
                String date = df.format(cal.getTime());//Returns Date
                
                
               

                if(resultSet.isFirst()){
                     System.out.print(date +"   "+ resultSet.getString("eventDate"));
                    while(resultSet.next()){
                        if(resultSet.getString("eventDate").equals(date)){
                            JsonObject dayObj =  Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add(date, resultSet.getInt("total")).build();
                            jsonArrayBuilder.add(dayObj);
                            break;
                        }else{
                            //if the end of resultset is reached and the date has no value, set it to zero
                            if(resultSet.isLast()){
                                JsonObject dayObj =  Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add(date, 0).build();
                                jsonArrayBuilder.add(dayObj);
                            }
                        }
                    } //end of while loop
                }else{
                    JsonObject dayObj =  Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add(date, 0).build();
                    jsonArrayBuilder.add(dayObj);
                }
            }//end of date loop
            
            data = (JsonObject) Json.createObjectBuilder().add("data", jsonArrayBuilder).build();
            System.out.print(data);
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Events.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
            DatabaseUtilities.closeConnection(resultSet, preparedStatement);
        }
        
        return data;
    }
    
}
```

How can i change the format of this json data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you need to use `createArrayBuilder` instead of `createObjectBuilder`

something like...

```
public static JsonObject weeksEventsGraph(){
    ThisWeek week = GetTime.weekDates();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    JsonObject data = null;

    sql ="SELECT DATE(`eventApprovedOn`) AS eventDate, sum(`eventId`) as total FROM " +
        "events WHERE DATE(eventApprovedOn) >= ? AND DATE(eventApprovedOn) <= ? " +
        "AND `eventStatus` = 1 GROUP BY `eventApprovedOn`";

    try {
        preparedStatement = DatabaseUtilities.createConnection(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,week.getStart());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,week.getEnd());
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        for(int i = Calendar.SUNDAY; i <= Calendar.SATURDAY; i++) {
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
            String date = df.format(cal.getTime());//Returns Date

            if(resultSet.isFirst()){
                 System.out.print(date +"   "+ resultSet.getString("eventDate"));
                while(resultSet.next()){
                    if(resultSet.getString("eventDate").equals(date)){
                        JsonObject dayObj = Json.createArrayBuilder();
                        dayObj.add(date);
                        dayObj.add(resultSet.getInt("total"));
                        jsonArrayBuilder.add(dayObj);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        //if the end of resultset is reached and the date has no value, set it to zero
                        if(resultSet.isLast()){
                            JsonObject dayObj = Json.createArrayBuilder();
                            dayObj.add(date);
                            dayObj.add(0);
                            jsonArrayBuilder.add(dayObj);
                        }
                    }
                } //end of while loop
            }else{
                JsonObject dayObj = Json.createArrayBuilder();
                dayObj.add(date);
                dayObj.add(0);
                jsonArrayBuilder.add(dayObj);
            }
        }//end of date loop

        System.out.print(jsonArrayBuilder);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Events.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        DatabaseUtilities.closeConnection(resultSet, preparedStatement);
    }

    return data;
}
```